# Inserting nil objects into an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

If we have an API that requires only 2 out of an objects 5 properties and iPhone app doesn't require them to instantiate an object, when the object is used in the params NSDicitionary the app will crash. I was told NSDictionary will not let you assign nil values, as when it reaches nil it thinks its finished. Does objective-c have a way to spit out an objects non-nil properties into an NSDictionary?

Example:

```
[Drunk alloc] init];
drunk.started_drinking = [NSDate date];
drunk.stopped_drinking (we don't set this because he is still a drunk)
drunk.fat = YES;
drunk.dumb = YES;


parameters:@{

             @"auth_token" :token,
             @"name" : drunk.name, @"date_started" : drunk.started_drinking,
             @"date_stopped" : drunk.stopped_drinking, 
             @"prescribing_doctor" : drunk.fat,
             @"pharmacy" : drunk.dumb

            }
```

This will crash when it gets to the stopped_drinking property.  Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Why not use another value?  Perhaps NULL?

Comment: How can you add NULL for an NSDate?

Comment: Just assign NULL to it like you would anything else.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's a bit long winded but you could do

```
static id ObjectOrNull(id object)
{
  return object ?: [NSNull null];
}

parameters:@{
  @"auth_token"         : ObjectOrNull(token),
  @"name"               : ObjectOrNull(drunk.name),
  @"date_started"       : ObjectOrNull(drunk.started_drinking),
  @"date_stopped"       : ObjectOrNull(drunk.stopped_drinking),
  @"prescribing_doctor" : ObjectOrNull(drunk.fat),
  @"pharmacy"           : ObjectOrNull(drunk.dumb),
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `return` line be `return object ? object : [NSNull null];`?

Comment: @rmaddy Have you tried it? This is short hand for the same thing, which is actually quite neat and concise I think

Comment: I actually tried to find out if that was some valid shorthand but didn't find anything. Oddly I didn't try it. I'm not convinced it is a good idea. Good to know though.

Comment: Any reason why you think it might not be a good idea? I use it all the time but I'm still slightly undecided on it.

Comment: I learned the ternary operator 25 years ago. Today is the first I've seen this shortcut. I may grow to like it. After all these years, my first reaction to this wax that it was a typo and it is unclear. It's too terse.

Comment: @rmaddy I guess coming from Ruby I'm used to this usage with 'a ||= default'

Comment: Is there any good swift alternative? Because in swift 3.0 it became even longer:
    ObjectOrNull(object: name)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot insert `nil` into collections (dictionaries, arrays, index sets, etc).

You can, however, insert `[NSNull null]` into them as this is [what they made it for](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Inserting objects into the dictionary becomes quite easy (if the property is `nil`, insert an `NSNull` instead). Then, when pulling things out of the dictionary, a quick `if(myReturnedObject == [NSNull null])` will tell you if the returned value is valid, as `NSNull` is a singleton and thus every `NSNull` is in fact the same object.

**Edit:** Paul.s has an excellent example of insertion behavior for your case, complete with [ternary operator usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

**Edit Again:** Despite the below comment, it is factually confirmed *in the Apple docs linked above* that NSNull does not crash when added to collections.

Comment: CrimsonDiego - now you can delete your comment, because there is no "loretoparisi"'s comment any more. When I was reading your answer, and when I saw your comment, it is  misleaded me.