# Store Empty NSMutableArray in NSDictionary

Tags: ios

I use a plist to store data locally on my app (similar to a Contacts-like app). When the user creates a new contact, and inputs values for name, phone #, etc. the app saves the contact, and then writes the data to a plist. However, one of the properies of my Person class is an NSMutableArray, and is not editable until after the contact has been created. But, when I save the data to the plist, I run into the problem of putting an empty NSMutableArray into an NSDictionary. (The console says that I can't store an object with a value of nil in a dictionary).

So, my question: how do I store an empty NSMutableArray in a dictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810875/inserting-nil-objects-into-an-nsdictionary

Comment: see this you have to store NSNull in the dictionary.because they are collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with storing an empty array in a dictionary.
For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
dict[@"array"] = array;
```

Storing a nil pointer that's declared as a pointer to an array **would** be a problem, however.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "storing a nil pointer that's declared as a pointer to an array"? What's the difference?

Comment: If you replace `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];` with `NSMutableArray *array = nil;`, the code I wrote would fail because it would be a nil pointer instead of an empty array.